# Azure Function is returning list of values but it the list appears empty in Chrome

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-8.0

I have the following Azure Function:

```
[Function("GetList")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetList(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "list")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await GetMyList();
                return result != null
                    ? new OkObjectResult(result)
                    : new NotFoundObjectResult("No results");
            }
}
```

The result is of type IList with values of type MyObject. If I debug the function I can see that the list is filled with objects that have values. However in Chrome I get a list with empty values like this:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

MyObject looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public string Prop1;
        public string Prop2;
    }
```

I also tried using HttpResponseData as a response but with the same result.

This used to work in .Net 6 but after upgrading to .Net 8 its not returning the values. Should this be implemented differently in .Net8?

Comment: Please show the definition of `class MyObject`.

Comment: Hi, question updated with MyObject

Comment: You named it Prop1, Prop2, but actually those are *fields*, not properties. Try adding `{ get; set; }` after each because AFAIK serialization only is done for public Properties.

Comment: Seems that some serialization settings changed, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62718200/2501279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree and thank you @Peter B for your suggestion.

You need to add `{get; set;}` in your `MyObject` class.

I have tried your code I was also getting the same output.

[image]

I added `{get; set;}` for *fields* and it worked for me.

**#My Code:**
**`.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>My.Namespace</RootNamespace>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />

  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`HttpTrigger1.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class HttpTrigger1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HttpTrigger1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HttpTrigger1>();
        }

        [Function("HttpTrigger1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route ="list")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

                        try
            {
                var result = await GetMyList();
                return result != null
                    ? new OkObjectResult(result)
                    : new NotFoundObjectResult("No results");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<List<MyObject>> GetMyList()
        {
            return new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject { Prop1 = "Vivek", Prop2 = "Shandilya" },
            new MyObject { Prop1 = "Vivek", Prop2 = "Vaibhav" },

        };
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Prop1 {get; set;}
        public string Prop2 {get; set;}
    }
}
```

**`program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`local.settings.json`:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**
[image]

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Edge:**

[image]